# Invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter in Apache Commons CSV library

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-csv

I am getting the following error while parsing the CSV file using the [Apache Commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) library.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: (line 2) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter

at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.parseEncapsulatedToken(Lexer.java:275)
at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:152)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.nextRecord(CSVParser.java:450)
at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.getRecords(CSVParser.java:327)
at parse.csv.file.CSVFileParser.main(CSVFileParser.java:29)
```

What's the meaning of this error ?

Comment: Can you show your csv file line 2 in specific if it is long?

Comment: Here is the sample line 2: "---","88104310D64DCG","10-20-2014","10:03 AM","10-20-2014","10:03 AM","00:00:00"," "," ","172.21.128.74"," ","h323",256," ","OUTGOING",45,1,0," "," ","user:---","172.21.128.74"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","Failed Attempt;"The call has ended.; Rolling Over."",16,0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0,0,0.0,0.0,0,0

Comment: One more observation is that if I open the CSV file in Microsoft Excel Workbook, make some modification and then save it. Now run the parser program which works!!

Comment: @SanthoshSridhar Please put that additional information neatly into the Question rather than posting as comments. Use the "edit" link below your Question’s tags (if in a web browser).

Answer (score 52):

We ran into this issue when we had embedded quote in our data.

```
0,"020"1,"BS:5252525  ORDER:99999"4
```

Solution applied was `CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withQuote(null);`

@Cuga tip helped us to resolve. Thanks @Cuga

Full code is

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withQuote(null);
    String fileName = "test.csv";

    fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
    CSVParser csvFileParser = new CSVParser(fileReader, csvFileFormat);

    List<CSVRecord> csvRecords = csvFileParser.getRecords();

    for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvRecords) {
        System.out.println(csvRecord);
    }
    csvFileParser.close();
}
```

Result is

```
CSVRecord [comment=null, mapping=null, recordNumber=1, values=[0, "020"1, "BS:5252525  ORDER:99999"4]]
```

Answer (score 10):

That line in the CSV file contains an invalid character between one of your cells and either the end of line, end of file, or the next cell. A very common cause for this is a failure to escape your encapsulating character (the character that is used to "wrap" each cell, so CSV knows where a cell (token) starts and ends.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution to the problem.
One of my CSV file has an attribute as follows:
***"attribute with nested "quote" "***

Due to nested quote in the attribute the parser fails.

To avoid the above problem escape the nested quote as follows:
***"attribute with nested """"quote"""" "***

This is the one way to solve the problem.

Comment: Looks like [the Answer by Steve Siebert](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26730109/642706) was correct. I suggest you accept his Answer (click the big empty checkmark), delete your own Answer while moving its text to a comment on his Answer.

Answer (score 2):

We ran into this in this same error with data containing quotes in otherwise unquoted input.  I.e.:

```
some cell|this "cell" caused issues|other data
```

It was hard to find, but in [Apache's docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withQuote-java.lang.Character-), they mention the `withQuote()` method which can take `null` as a value.

We were getting the exact same error message and this (thankfully) ended up fixing the issue for us.

Comment: Thanks @Cuga. We had embedded quote and we had parse with data. Your comment helped us.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when I forgot to call `.withNullString("")` on my `CSVFormat`. Basically, this exception always occurs when:

- your quote symbol is wrong
- your null string representation is wrong
- your column separator char is wrong

Make sure you know the details of your format. Also, some programs use leading byte-order-marks (for example, Excel uses `\uFEFF`) to denote the encoding of the file. This can also trip up your parser.