# Ignoring delimiter in quote-enclosed field in Apache Commons CSV / OpenCSV?

Tags: java, csv, noclassdeffounderror, apache-commons, apache-commons-csv

I have to parse a csv file which has fields that can look like the following:

```
("FOO, BAR BAZ", 42)
```

And yield the two fields:

```
FOO, BAR BAZ  
42
```

I'm not sure how to do this succinctly using Apache Commons CSV or OpenCSV, so I'm looking for some guidance. It may just be that I don't fully understand the `org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat` property "quoteChar" [which is touched on in the documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withQuote-char-) but never clearly explained anywhere I could find. If so, it'd be very helpful if you could point me towards better documentation of that feature.

Here's a brief example that shows my problem as well as what I've tried and the results:

```
        String test = "(\"FOO, BAR BAZ\", 42)";
        int numTries = 5;
        CSVParser[] tries = new CSVParser[numTries];
        tries[0] = CSVParser.parse(line, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator("\n"));//BAR BAZ"
        tries[1] = CSVParser.parse(line, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withQuote('"'));//BAR BAZ"
        tries[2] = CSVParser.parse(line, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withQuote(null));//BAR BAZ"
        tries[3] = CSVParser.parse(line, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withQuote('"').withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.NON_NUMERIC));//BAR BAZ"
        tries[4] = CSVParser.parse(line, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withRecordSeparator(")\n("));//BAR BAZ"

        for(int i = 0; i < numTries; i++){
            CSVRecord record = tries[i].getRecords().get(0);
            System.out.println(record.get(1));//.equals("42"));
        }
```

Note that it works fine if you exclude the parentheses from the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OpenCSV`'s `CSVReader` to read the data and get the data elements as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("C:\\Sample.txt"));
                CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(fr);) {
            String[] data = csvReader.readNext();
            for(String data1 : data) {
                System.out.println(data1);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: And it will just ignore delimiters which are enclosed in quotes by default?

Comment: Because that's what my question is about.

Answer (score 0):

For me the default-format of commons-csv does the right thing for a correctly formatted CSV message:

```
    Reader in = new StringReader("\"FOO, BAR BAZ\", 42");
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(in);
    for (CSVRecord record : records) {
        for(int i = 0;i < record.size();i++) {
            System.out.println("At " + i + ": " + record.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Leads to:

```
At 0: FOO, BAR BAZ
At 1:  42
```

For the specially formatted lines you likely need to do a bit more handling top remove those brackets:

```
    BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(
            new StringReader("(\"FOO, BAR BAZ\", 42)\n(\"FOO, BAR FOO\", 44)"));

    while(true) {
        String line = lineReader.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }

        String adjustedLine = line.substring(1, line.length() - 1);
        records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(new StringReader(adjustedLine));
        for (CSVRecord record : records) {
            for (int i = 0; i < record.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("At " + i + ": " + record.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's what I expected, however I get `invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter` and the solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729799/invalid-char-between-encapsulated-token-and-delimiter-in-apache-commons-csv-libr) suggest changing _withQuote_ to fix it.

Comment: Can include a minimal test-case in your question? Because I don't see where your code is different, mine works exactly as I posted it and does not report any error. At least check which quotes you have in your text, it may fail if they are "typographical quotes", e.g. added in Word.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. You don't have the enclosing parentheses around your input line. Probably my fault though -- they were initially left out of the question. I've added a test case, though.

Comment: You will need to split the lines and remove those parantheses manually before doing the CSV parsiing, likely none of the libs will allow to parse things like that...

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with opencsv as follows:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NewClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String fileName = "C:\\yourFile.csv";
        String [] nextLine;
        // use the three arg constructor to tell the reader which delimiter you have in your file(2nd arg : here ',')                                                          
        // you can change this to '\t' if you have tab separeted file or ';' or ':' ... whatever your delimiter is
        // (3rd arg) '"' if your fields are double quoted or '\'' if single quoted or no 3rd arg if the fields are not quoted
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName), ',' ,'"');
        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        // each line represented by String[], and each field as an element of the array
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {        
            System.out.println("nextLine[0]: " +nextLine[0]);
            System.out.println("nextLine[1]: " +nextLine[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work even if only some of the fields (i.e. string fields) are quoted?