# Using Same Escape and Quote Character Breaks CSV

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I have a simple CSV file like this:

```
SellerProductID;ProductTextLong
1000;"a ""good"" Product"
```

And this is the try to read it in with Apache CSV:

```java
    try (Reader reader = new StringReader(content)) {
      CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(';').withHeader().withEscape('"').withQuote('"');
      CSVParser records = format.parse(reader);
      System.out.println(records.iterator().next());
    }
```

That doesn't work because of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: IOException reading next record: java.io.IOException: (startline 2) EOF reached before encapsulated token finished
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$CSVRecordIterator.getNextRecord(CSVParser.java:145)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$CSVRecordIterator.next(CSVParser.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$CSVRecordIterator.next(CSVParser.java:137)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: (startline 2) EOF reached before encapsulated token finished
    at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.parseEncapsulatedToken(Lexer.java:288)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:158)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser.nextRecord(CSVParser.java:674)
    at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$CSVRecordIterator.getNextRecord(CSVParser.java:142)
    ... 3 more
```

Other CSV tools (e.g. Google Sheets) can load the CSV just fine.

It works if I use another quote or escape character, but sadly the customer's CSV is set.

How do I configure Apache CSV to allow the same escape and quote character? Or is there any way to modify a stream to replace the quote characters on the fly (the files are gigantic)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire problem is that " is not the "escape character".

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values):

> Embedded double quote characters may then be represented by a pair of consecutive double quotes, or by prefixing a double quote with an escape character such as a backslash.

So in this case, "" is just two quote characters next to each other, while the escape character is a differenct character used to escape quotes or line breaks or separators.

This fixes it (note that `withEscape()` is called differently, but the example data doesn't show what the escape character actually is):

```java
try (Reader reader = new StringReader(content)) {
    CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(';').withHeader().withEscape('/').withQuote('"');
    CSVParser records = format.parse(reader);
    System.out.println(records.iterator().next());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have looked over your issue and this [article](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/2618144) and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729799/invalid-char-between-encapsulated-token-and-delimiter-in-apache-commons-csv-libr) might help you. Try to use also with `.withNullString("")`.